# SQL Server Management Studio Plugin for Diagrams

Tags: sql-server, plugins, ssms

Is there any plugin for SQL Server Management Studio which add more functions and ease of use in database diagrams.

Comment: :( SQL Management Studio could have more usability features (coloring, labeling of keys, unique/index etc) in diagrams

Comment: and relationship lines that connect with the fields joined.  This happens in the view designer so why not for diagrams?

Comment: It's 5 years that I am waiting for something like that in SSMS ... Probably Microsoft does not make enough money on that tool.

Comment: As more developers adopt EF I imagine the designer there will get more attention.  I don't think the one in SSMS has changed since Enterprise Manager days.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, no.  The current modelling tool is called "Davinci" and has remain essentially unchanged since it was introduced in SQL 7.0, circa 1997.

I suspect Microsoft is intentionally not releasing better modelling tools, perhaps as an anti-trust settlement or at least good-will.  They could easily do a lot of damage to the modeling-tool software market by including a decent one with SQL Server for free.  That is just my opinion, however.